# Rearranging \cite arguments

Tags: citing, strings, comma-separated-list

I have the following requirement for my thesis: If I cite multiple citations, I should cite my papers first.
The names of all my papers start with “`my:`”.

So I want to define a new command that should work in the following way:

```
\newcite{paper1, my:paper2, paper3, my:paper4}
```

This command should be equivalent to the following one

```
\cite{my:paper2, my:paper4}, \cite{paper1, paper3}
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I doubt that latex can sort by label name, at least not in this particular fashion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the powerful capabilities of `xparse` and `l3regex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{my:paper1,
 author={BCP, X.},
 title={My paper 1},
 journal={J.},
 year={2014},
}
@article{my:paper2,
 author={BCP, X.},
 title={My paper 2},
 journal={J.},
 year={2015},
}
@article{paper1,
 author={Uthor, A.},
 title={Not my paper 1},
 journal={J.},
 year={2014},
}
@article{paper2,
 author={Riter, W.},
 title={Not my paper 2},
 journal={J.},
 year={2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % only needed for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mcite}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l_bcp_mycites_clist
  \clist_clear:N \l_bcp_othercites_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A my\: } { ##1 }
     {
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_bcp_mycites_clist { ##1 }
     }
     {
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_bcp_othercites_clist { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_bcp_mycites_clist
   {
    \bcp_cite:V \l_bcp_othercites_clist
   }
   {
    \bcp_cite:V \l_bcp_mycites_clist
    \clist_if_empty:NF \l_bcp_othercites_clist
     {
      , ~ \bcp_cite:V \l_bcp_othercites_clist
     }
   }
 }

\cs_set_eq:NN \bcp_cite:n \cite
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bcp_cite:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Mixed citation: \mcite{paper1, my:paper1, paper2, my:paper2}

My citations only: \mcite{my:paper2,my:paper1}

Other citations only: \mcite{paper1,paper2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `mcite` command scans the argument and builds two distinct comma separated lists based on whether the next key starts with `my:` or not. Then these lists are delivered as arguments to `\cite`. A comma and a space are inserted in between if and only if both lists are not empty.

[image]

Comment: This should be a package